# Unknown Issues with Texture Painting? Not Working? 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

new to Blender here so I am more than willing to accept this as user error, however I would really love to learn and figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have watched 3 separate tutorials on youtube for texture painting in 2.8, and I follow all the instructions and up until I am able to actually start painting everything seems to be in order, and then the actual painting on the object does not work, nothing shows up(on the model or in the uv map).

For example I have gotten to 2:33 in this video and followed all rules and nothing comes past that! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svzKoq3vew0&t=2s

Here is a screenshot of my workstation and model unwrapped for people who might be able to visually see what I'm doing wrong!
[image]

If this is not an appropriate place for this question, or is too novice of a problem I apologize, I tried finding this problem elsewhere and I didn't see anyone with the same issues. Thanks even if I cant find help!

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to an older save of the bird and I was able to make it work, the only difference being that the later save had particles on it. So I assume I just did things in the wrong order!

But thanks everyone for the answers and trying to help me!

So texture painting before adding hair/feathers. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Normal' Problem here is usually that your Face Normals are pointed inward. To check this in 2.8, switch to Edit Mode and press the overlay icon to find the option to show Face Normals, and correct the direction in Edit Mode before returning to Texture Paint mode.
[image]
Happy Painting!!

Comment: I did what you told me, and it was fixed and I went back into texture painting and still nothing shows up when I paint, Thanks for the answer though!